# Creating a "white" image in numpy (2-D image)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

Looks like I seem to have some fundamental gaps in my understanding of how images are represented in numpy arrays.

```
img = np.ones([100,100,3], dtype=np.uint8)*255
plt.imshow(img)
```

The above code creates a "white" 3 channel image.

Each pixel has the value [255,255,255]

Understood.

Now I'd like create a "white" gray scale image. I don't really need RGB channels to store a white image, do I?

```
img_bw = np.ones([100,100], dtype=np.uint8)*255
plt.imshow(img_bw, cmap = "gray")
```

This creates a "black image" even though value at each pixel location is 255?

Okay, let me just take my earlier 3 channel white image and convert it to grayscale and see what the numpy array looks like.

```
img_bw1 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
plt.imshow(img_bw1, cmap = "gray")
```

This gives me a "black image" as well?

So what exactly does the numpy matrix for a grayscale "white image" look like?

```
img = io.imread("https://www.colorcombos.com/images/colors/FFFFFF.png" , as_grey=True)
plt.imshow(img*255, cmap = "gray")
```

This is a white image. Each pixel in this matrix has a value of like 216 and above

```
plt.imshow(img, cmap = "gray")
```

This is also a white image. Each pixel in this matrix has a value of 0.86 and above.

I'm totally lost.

Questions -

1. How do I create a grayscale 2-D white image in numpy?
2. Why doesn't converting the 3 channel white image in numpy to grayscale using cv2.Color give me a white image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When displaying a 2D array using a colormap, matplotlib will first [normalize the data](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html#matplotlib-colors-normalize) such that it lies between 0 and 1.

Your white array is composed solely of 255's, when attempting to normalize an array of equal values, documentation states that they are all converted to 0 (see above link), resulting in a black rendering. To manually specify a range, use:

```
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

You can also try setting the first pixel in your `img_bw` array to any value <255 and using your original method to show it, you should see an all white image with a black square in the corner.

---

As for why this "worked":

```
img = io.imread("https://www.colorcombos.com/images/colors/FFFFFF.png" , as_grey=True)
plt.imshow(img*255, cmap = "gray")
```

There's a thin grey border around the [image in that link](https://www.colorcombos.com/images/colors/FFFFFF.png), so after normalization, the grey border (darkest part of the image) is scaled to 0 (black) and the rest of the white interior stays white.

Answer (score 0):

Using PIL to encode the array as an image is one way to go -

```
img_bw = np.ones([100,100], dtype=np.uint8)*255
img = Image.fromarray(img_bw)
img.show()
```

**Output**

[image]

For black, if you just change to `img_bw = np.ones([100,100], dtype=np.uint8)*0` you get - 
[image]